# Multiplying two integers if initial input is an odd integer in C++

Tags: c++, integer-arithmetic

I'm working on a homework assignment for a beginning C++ class and I'm a bit lost.
Here's the assignment:

Create a c++ program which ask the user to input a number.

The output of the program should be one of the following:
You entered an EVEN number.
OR
You entered an ODD number.

if the user entered an ODD number, ask them to enter another number.
Multiply this number by the first number and output the result.

The even/odd part is pretty easy- I got that part to work.  I've gotten completely lost on the second part.  I'm getting so many lines of errors I can't even figure out where the beginning is.  If anyone could give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
        int num1; // This is the original number entered by the user.
        int num2; // This is the second number entered if the first number is odd.
        cout << "Enter a number: "<< endl;
        cin >> num1 >> endl;
        if (num1 % 2 == 0) {
                cout << num << " Your number is even." << endl;
}       if (num1 % 2 != 0) {
                cout << num1 << " Your number is odd. Please enter another number: “<< endl;
                cin >> num1 >> endl;
        } // end of if odd
        cout << " Your two numbers multiplied equals (num1 *= num2)” << endl;

} // end of main ()
```

Comment: You ask for a second number and then do: `cin >> num1 >> endl;` shouldn't that go in `num2` ? Also you say you get many errors but didn't actually tell us what those errors were. (P.S: `cout << num` this is invalid, you haven't declared `num` as a variable)

Comment: You should probably remember to `return` a value off of `main` (instead of letting control flow off the end).

Comment: I think the syntax highlighting makes it pretty obvious you have some stray smart quotation marks in there. `cin >> endl;` should disappear. @inetknght, 0 is returned when you flow off the end of `main`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int num1; // This is the original number entered by the user.
    int num2; // This is the second number entered if the first number is odd.
    cout << "Enter a number: "<< endl;
    cin >> num1;
    if (num1 % 2 == 0) {
        cout << num1 << " Your number is even." << endl;
    }       
    else {
        cout << num1 << " Your number is odd. Please enter another number: " << endl;
        cin >> num2;
        cout << " Your two numbers multiplied equals " << num1*num2 << endl;
    } // end of if odd
    return 0;        
} // end of main ()
```

Here's fixed code. You tried to `cout << num`, but there's no `num` variable, should be `num1`, also it's wrong to `cin >> endl`.

What was unexpected, your `”` at the end is not a `"` but something else and it produces a lot of errors.

Answer (score 0):

The part for the odd values

```
if (num1 % 2 != 0) {
    cout << num1 << " Your number is odd. Please enter another number: “<< endl;
    cin >> num2 >> endl;
    cout << " Your two numbers multiplied equals:" << (num1 * num2) << endl;
            }
```

Comment: The only change I see is that `num1` doesn't get assigned the result of the multiplication, which is good, but makes no observable difference.

Comment: but this code is calculating num1 * num2. The OPs code doesnt. So thats an improvement:)

Comment: True, I did miss the s/num1/num2/ in the input. It's generally a good idea to highlight what changed, and that's a good example of why.

Comment: Ok!  I found two problems.  First was the num/num1 issue.  Thank you for pointing that out! The second super weird issue was that I somehow had two different kinds of quotation marks.  Possibly because I was using TextEdit for some of it.  Now I'm getting WAY fewer errors, but they're all error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token errors.  Pasting the updated code below.

Comment: Pardon the formatting.  I'm trying to figure out how to do that properly.  I'll fix it as soon as I figure out how!

Comment: Ok, I can't figure out how to format, but I'm getting the "error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token" errors in several lines.  Example:

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
     int num1;
     int num2;
     cout << "Enter a number: " <<;
     cin >> num1 >> ;
     if (num1 % 2 == 0)
          cout << num1 << " Your number is even." <<;
     else 
          cout << num1 << " Your number is odd.  Please enter another number: " << ;
          cin >> num2 >> ;
          cout << " Your two numbers multiplied equals: " << (num1 *= num2) << end;
}

Comment: there is a missing "l" at your last `endl` and why do you use the `=*` operator instead of the `*` operator? Use the `*` operator:)

Comment: Ok.  I have a new code that seems to be ok, but now I'm getting a weird new error when I try to compile.  Code is:

Comment: [code]
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main () {
        int num1; 
        int num2; 
        cout<< "Enter a number: "<<endl;
        cin>>num1;
        if (num1 % 2 == 0) {
                cout<< num1<< " Your number is even." <<endl;
        }
         else   {
                cout<<num1<< " Your number is odd. Please enter another number: " <<endl;
                cin>>num2;
                cout<< " Your two numbers multiplied equals: " <<(num1*num2)<<endl;
        }
} // end of main ()
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

after corrections

```
if (num1 % 2 != 0) {
cout << num1 << " Your number is odd. Please enter another number:"<< endl;
cin >> num2;
cout << " Your two numbers multiplied equals:" << (num1 * num2) << endl;
}
```

do not place formulas between quotaion marks. this turns them into strings or chars that cant be executed as desire. ie `cout << " Your two numbers multiplied equals (num1 *= num2)” << endl;`

placing the statement `cout << " Your two numbers multiplied equals (num1 *= num2)” << endl;` out side the if statement causes the statement to be run even if the number was not odd. this doesnt comply with the assignment.  and num2 being null still will cause an error